# What steps should I take to securely manage and validate sessions on all my PHP pages?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I currently use PHP sessions (without database saving) to identify users on a small website. However, I would like to make it more secure by saving session data to a MySQL database along with using a cookie with PHP.

I'm thinking of having a PHP script which I will include on every page which will:

- Try to validate a session based on a database entry
- Create a session if needed
- Set special session variables I might need

Is this the best way to go about things? Am I missing anything in my script?

Comment: What makes you think that replacing the standard, mature, well tested session system built into PHP with a homebrew one would be more secure?

Comment: I'm not replacing PHP sessions ... I'm using them ALONG WITH a MySQL solution. From what I understand it's standard practice.

Comment: So you'd be keeping the data in the PHP managed session and a clone of it in your database? Again, how would that be more secure?

Comment: Because a cookie can be falsified...

Comment: What is the added value of saving session data in the database?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I don't think security is your concern here.  It seems like you just want to know how to handle users?

Comment: @MaxMackie — You have to associate the session with the browser somehow and a cookie is the best way to do that. Using MySQL instead of or as well as the standard PHP session storage mechanism isn't going to change how you perform that association though, so adding MySQL to the mix is certainly not going to help with that.

Comment: @Quentin: At login, I can (1) generate a PHP session/cookie and (2) store that information along with some specific user stuff in a database entry. That way each time the user visits a page, their session is validated against the information entered into the database. It can protect against false sessions and cookie manipulation.

Comment: @MaxMackie — That is what the built in PHP session management system does (except that it doesn't use MySQL to store the data). There no such thing as a false session, sessions depend on the server creating them in the first place. Cookie manipulation doesn't do any good unless the cookie can be extracted from the user who should have it, and if that can be extracted then so can any other cookie data that is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

Session automatically try to use cookies for session ID.

The common practice is to store everything important into `$_SESSION` on login (and check only for privileges change).

If you want to make it more secure you may store `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']` into session and check them on each request.

The last thing I can think of right now is checking 'life time of session' manually.

Anyway I think that using https instead of http would bring you much more safety than reinventing sessions.

Storing each request/session into DB would make sense only if you needed to have special handling for parallel request.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty big question.  You want to do a bit of research on learning the tools I'll provide you for the job.  I cannot write every detail about them here, but I'll try to get you pointed in the right direction.

1. check the user cookie to see if they have your session id variable set. if it isn't, start them a new session and offer a login perhaps.
2. if they have the cookie, check if it is a valid session id
3. if it is, load that session.

You'll need tools like [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), [session_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php), [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), [$_COOKIE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).  Making a users table is a whole other topic really.

Answer (score 1):

I work with MVC's all the time that do just exactly what your referring to. Its a real piece of junk setting it up that way, but it can be useful in certain situations.

But the most important thing you should know is that when combining the login to an active session, it won't really make it more secure unless you use 2 session identifiers. is this what you want to do?

This would also be useful if you wanted to track where users log-in from. Gook luck!